# Humanizing time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a number of products that are perishable. Therefore, each product has an attribute called hours_expiration that tells how many hours the product can be used before it goes bad.

For ex, apple expires in 168 hours; nut expires in 4320 hours.

Given, the product's hours-to-expiration and the current time (Time.now or Date.now), how can I humanize the time-to-expiration in some of the following sample ways?

Your item is set to expire in about:

- 6 months and 14 days
- 1 month and 13 days
- 1 month and 1 day
- 27 days
- 1 day
- 23 hours
- 1 hour
- 50 minutes
- 1 minute

Looking for something robust and simple!

Comment: I would avoid `months` - month can be 28-31 days long. I would prefer days (and perhaps weeks).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[The `distance_of_time_in_words` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) seems to be what you ask for.

Answer (score 3):

Another easy helper is `time_ago_in_words`: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words

The method name might sound like it can only deal with past dates but actually it handles future dates just fine. You can try it in your rails console:

```
expiration_date = Time.now + 5.days 
puts "Expires in #{helper.time_ago_in_words(expiration_date)}"
```

*"Expires in 5 days"*

Answer (score 1):

Look at Distance of time docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words